# How to emulate Lisp's let function in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, evaluation

I'm trying to write a `let` function that allows me to do things like:

```
let(a=2, b=3, a+b)
>>> 5
```

Currently I'm stuck with

```
let <- function(..., expr) {
  with(list(...), quote(expr))
}
```

which doesn't work at all. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
let <- function(..., expr) {
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    dots <- list(...)
    eval(expr, dots)
}

let(a = 2, b = 3, expr = a+b)
# [1] 5
```

**Edit**: Alternatively, if you don't want to have to name the expression-to-be-evaluated (i.e. passing it in via `expr`), *and* if you are certain that it will always be the last argument, you could do something like this.

```
let <- function(...) {
    args <- as.list(sys.call())[-1]
    n <- length(args)
    eval(args[[n]], args[-n])
}

let(a = 2, b = 3, a + b)
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like `expr` has to be passed as a named argument, otherwise it's captured by `...`, right?

Comment: @Ernest: yes.  All arguments after `...` must be named.

Comment: @Ernest -- Take a look at the second version of `let()`, which I just added. I think it may address the question underlying your comment...

Comment: ...or just put `expr` first: `let <- function(expr, ...) eval(substitute(expr), list(...))`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: The second version works exactly as I had in mind, thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Nice suggestion, but since `expr` may be quite long, I think it's better if it's the last argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
let <- function(a,b, expr=a+b){return(expr)}
let(2,3)
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only seems to work with the default expression -- `let(a=2,b=3,expr=a-b)` gives an error.